# Does it matter if I use GlobalScope for application-level coroutines in KMM?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I have an `ViewModel` Kotlin class in a single-Activity Android app that starts coroutines that talk to an application-level repository.

In Android I use the `ViewModel` scope with `Dispatchers.IO` to start the coroutines.

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO, CoroutineStart.DEFAULT, someFunction)
```

In iOS I can't use `viewModelScope`, but I still create my "ViewModel"s at the application-level in my iOS project. So I use `GlobalScope` with `Dispatchers.Default` (being as `Dispatchers.IO` doesn't exist in iOS projects).

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
  someFunction()
}
```

I understand that `GlobalScope` is now marked as delicate, and it doesn't conform to Kotlin's structured concurrency. So instead I used

```kotlin
MainScope().launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
 someFunction()
}
```

But I'm wonder if, for my case, since my coroutines are application-level, it doesn't actually matter if I use `GlobalScope`? I can't see any downsides, but maybe there are some. Any input would be appreciated.

(I'm using the experimental memory model for KMM, in case this matters)